# Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I am aware that this question has been asked before but none of the suggestions worked for me.

Bluetooth was working fine in Ubuntu 16.04 LTE then I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and bluetooth no longer works.

I have a Toshiba Satellite Pro C50 A1K9 laptop and use the internal wifi to link to a Bose Soundlink Mini Soundlink speaker.  When I enable all the necessary screen switches - "Bluetooth ON, Visible ON, Bose Soundlink Mini Soundlink ON", the Bose unit bleeps showing that it has connected through bluetooth.  This is confirmed on the laptop as the 'Sound' window shows "Play Sound through HiFi Bose Mini Soundlink" with an appropriate volume control.  If I then run the mpv Media Player and drag and drop a sound file onto the window in the usual way, no sound is heard despite the fact that the media player shows that the file is playing.  The same result happens with the VLC media player.  There is clearly a bug in the internal bluetooth software in Ubuntu 18.04 which needs a fix.

Comment: I have solved it after much work.  I think what must have happened is that a garbled bluetooth code must have been transmitted somehow.  Even turning the Bose off then on did not work.  What was needed was with bluetooth all ON on the computer, and the Bose ON, hold down the bluetooth button on the Bose mini soundlink for 10 seconds, it bleeps and is rebooted and reconnects and hey presto the audio now works!  Hope this may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it after much work. I think what must have happened is that a garbled bluetooth code must have been transmitted somehow. Even turning the Bose off then on did not work. What was needed was with bluetooth all ON on the computer, and the Bose ON, hold down the bluetooth button on the Bose mini soundlink for 10 seconds, it bleeps and is rebooted and reconnects and hey presto the audio now works! Hope this may help someone else.